# Which network module i can use with cisco 2610 router

Tags: cisco, router

I have cisco 2610 router but it has only one ethernet interface.

I want to add more Fastethernet interface on it.

But i don't know which network module is for that router.

can anyone please guide me

Comment: Try this link: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/2600-series-multiservice-platforms/product_data_sheet0900aecd800fa5be.html

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are no FastEthernet WICs (only HWICs), and none of the 10/100 network modules are officially supported for the [2600 series](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_data_sheet09186a0080091b89.html) (except the 2691 in some cases). While at least [one person](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10228056/does-nm-1fe-tx-works-2610xm) has reported getting an NM-1FE-TX working in a 2620, the bigger problem you have is that the [2610 has limited throughput capacity](http://www.cisco.com/web/partners/downloads/765/tools/quickreference/routerperformance.pdf), and the benefit you'll see with a 100 Mbps interface over 10 Mbps will depend greatly on your configuration and the type of traffic you push through it. You may be better off looking for an NM-1E or NM-4E 10 Mbps card, both of which are definitely supported on the 2600 series.

Also, bear in mind that this platform and these modules are well past EOL, so you'll likely need to source parts from the used/refurb market.

Comment: Hi James, perhaps there is a misunderstanding... the 7Mbps performance figures you're quoting are 15Kpps at 64 byte packets; this isn't a real life limitation on the c2600 unless you're sending lots of small packets.  For imix traffic profiles (roughly 250 byte packets on average) 15Kpps is 30Mbps.  Thus 100M interfaces are useful

Comment: @MikePennington - I'd just point out that the figures provided by Cisco are also for a barebones configuration, and they make it clear that by enabling additional features and services, "performance will decline significantly from the given numbers". That said, I have never attempted to use a 2600 in this configuration, and I would defer to your experience over Cisco's theoreticals. I will update my answer accordingly.